# How can I resolve dynamic addresses (for APIs,DLLs etc.) to disassemble in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, dynamic-linking, memory-dump

I have memory dump of injected process. But the malware load libraries/functions dynamically and I need to resolve this. For example, If malware will use createThread, first get address of this function with getprocaddress then kept the pointer into a variable. To call function use variable.

So I need to resolve dynamic addresses to disassemble. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

you could write a script which will get all xref's to`GetProcAddress`then go one by one to check`GetProcAddress` second parametes `lpProcName` next follow disassembly trace return value `eax` to first memory write e.g. `mov dword ptr [unknown_ptr], eax` and rename the pointer.

For inspiration look at IDAscope plugin:
https://hex-rays.com/contests/2012/index.shtml#idascope
or funcap
https://hex-rays.com/contests/2013/index.shtml#funcap

Comment: Is this still possible to do statically even if a custom loader or calls to `GetProcAddress` itself is generated dynamically?

Comment: yes but more work and the results might be not that good